# Capacitor-JS Status Bar overlaps in IOS

Tags: ios, vue.js, nuxt.js, statusbar, capacitor

I'm using NuxtJS with a capacitor. The top status bar on an IOS device is overlapping while we scroll. I also added `"ios": {"contentInset": "always"}` in capacitor.config.json.

[image]

Despite the fact that I had also included CSS, it created extra space on the top side.

```js
body {
   padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom)
     env(safe-area-inset-left);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by adding following line in CAPViewBridgeController file

```
webView?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height)

webView?.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height;
```

Search for below function and update. The function should look like this

```
extension CAPBridgeViewController: CAPBridgeDelegate {
    internal var bridgedWebView: WKWebView? {
        webView?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height)
        webView?.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height;
        return webView
    }

    internal var bridgedViewController: UIViewController? {
        return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've wasted too much time trying to solve this problem.
viewport, inset, safe-area-inset etc... I've read most of the solutions I can find on google and bing.
And they were all useless.

After scolding my commit message, I tried to modify the ios native source without expectations.
Then it worked amazingly well.

Apply the source below at the bottom of the CAPBridgeViewController.swift file.

```
extension CAPBridgeViewController: CAPBridgeDelegate {
    internal var bridgedWebView: WKWebView? {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first;
        let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0;
        let height = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0;
        webView?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: height)
        webView?.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - height - bottomPadding;
        return webView
    }

    internal var bridgedViewController: UIViewController? {
        return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the previous answers, it worked me as well. But there was a problem occurred that statusBar's background was always black with UIStatusBarStyleDarkContent on notch Iphones (the models below the Iphone X just fine).

[image: Iphone 14 pro]

After making some changes for static background color on statusBar, everything is perfect now.
For my case i made background white because of my sticky header is also white. But you can change with any other colors on apple ui on the code below.

```
extension CAPBridgeViewController: CAPBridgeDelegate {
    public var bridgedWebView: WKWebView? {
        if let webView = webView {
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                let statusBar = UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero)
                statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white // Replace with your color
                UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBar)
            } else {
                if let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView {
                    statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white // Replace with your color
                }
            }
            
            webView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height)
            webView.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
            
            return webView
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    public var bridgedViewController: UIViewController? {
        return self
    }
}
```

result: [image]

**Note: If you dont know how to apply this changes;**
Follow Xcode -> pods -> development pods -> capacitor -> CAPBridgeViewController , change the code and then do `npx patch-package @capacitor/ios`. I did it like this on capacitor v5 but the package name could be directly capacitor the other versions if youre still using it.